# how do i back insert to a vector with a const pointer

Tags: c++, vector, constants

hello i have an error with the following code:
in my h file i got the following vector:

```
vector<Vehicale*> m_vehicalesVector;
```

and in my cpp file i got the following function:

```
void Adjutancy:: AddVehicale(const Vehicale* vehicaleToAdd)
{
    m_vehicalesVector.push_back(vehicaleToAdd);
}
```

seems like the `const Vehicale* vehicaleToAdd` is making the problem when i change it to a non const variable it works.
thanks in advance.

Comment: i understood my mistake... i should have define the vector like this vector<const Vehicale*> m_vehicalesVector;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m_vehicalesVector.push_back()` needs `Vchicale*` as its parameter, while `const Vehicale*` is given. Compiler denies this because `const` cannot be removed silently.

Change `vector<Vehicale*> m_vehicalesVector` to `vector<const Vehicale*> m_vehicalesVector` can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store a const pointer into a vector of non-const pointers since you could then use the non-const pointer to modify the object pointed to by the const pointer.

You can make it a vector of const pointers:

```
vector<const Vehicle*> m_vehiclesVector;
```

or pass in a non-const pointer.

You could also cast away const-ness:

```
m_vehiclesVector.push_back(const_cast<Vehicle *>(vehicleToAdd));
```

but I would strongly discourage that approach.